# Angular hide button while loading then re enable

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, callback

I have a component that loads an image when the button is clicked.

To avoid multiple clicks, I want to hide the button when clicked, display a text and re enable the button when the image is loaded.

I'm not sure why this code doesn't work.

Here's the html file:

```
<div class="row">
    <img [src]="url ? url : 'assets/image/evolution_s.png'" class="gan_generated mx-auto d- 
     block" alt="it is sad :'(">
    <img [src]="url ? url : 'assets/image/evolution_s.png'" class="gan_generated mx-auto d- 
     block" alt="it is sad :'(">
</div>
<div *ngIf="this.isClicked==false else waitBlock">
  <button type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-auto d-block"
          (click)="generate_and_show()">Generate Anime Faces</button>
</div>
<ng-template #waitBlock><p class="text-center">Please wait for the artist</p></ng-template>
```

and here's the component.ts:

```
export class GanComponent implements OnInit {
    public isClicked = false;

    constructor(private ganService: ImageGanService,
          private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    url: SafeUrl;

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    generate_and_show(): void {
        this.isClicked = true;
        this.ganService.request_image()
        .subscribe(response => {
          this.url = 
          this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(response));
        });
        this.isClicked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're changing the click status outside of the subscribe callback!

Comment: That was actually the solution, thank you. I don't understand though why it needs to be in the subscribe? it should be executed after the subscribe ends, right?

Comment: Absolutely not. I don't know how you could expect that to work.

Comment: Well I'm a beginner with Angular so I'm trying to understand. Is it because the subscribe is asynschronous? but then, does this mean that nothing can happen after the subcribe in a method?

Comment: You are right, it needs to be in the subscribe as that is async en triggers once the thing is done. Also, in your template it is better not to use ‘this’ in front of your component variables (like this. IsClicked).

Comment: thank you for the clarification. Will update the template too.

Comment: While it's particularly common with rxjs callbacks, it theoretically can apply to any callback. When you pass a function to another function, you don't know when the function you passed will be called. And working with promises, `async`/`await` enables abstracting over this complexity but angular, with its diehard commitment to RxJS, isn't very compatible with this abstraction